# Cloud Tasks App Engine target with relative URI throws Exception 400 : HttpRequest.url is required

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-tasks

I am trying to create a task using Google Cloud Tasks using the Python client `google-cloud-tasks==2.1.0` but I am getting an exception that HttpRequest.url is required. I am setting relative url which is a URL handling the task in my app.

The queue exists and has been created using:

```
gcloud task create queue notifications
```

The code:

```
client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()
parent = client.queue_path(project, location, queue)
task = {                                                                
  'app_engine_http_request': {                                        
    'http_method': tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,                        
    'relative_uri': notification_url,
    'body': payload.encode('utf-8')                       
  },                                                                  
  'http_request': {                                                   
    'headers': {"Content-type": "application/json"}                 
  }                                                                   
}
response = client.create_task(parent=parent, task=task)
```

The exact error that I receive is:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 HttpRequest.url is required
```

I am trying to create task in my App Engine Standard environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Donald was right, but i think there is a typo in the google docs he linked. I set my headers within `app_engine_http_request`, not `http_request`.

I don't think you can provide both `app_engine_http_request` and `http_request`, you can only do one. So like this:

```
     client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()
     parent = client.queue_path(project, location, queue)
     task = {                                                                
         'app_engine_http_request': {                                        
             'http_method': tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,                        
             'relative_uri': notification_url,
             'headers': {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             'body': payload.encode('utf-8')                       
         }                                                                 
     }
     response = client.create_task(parent=parent, task=task)
```

https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudtasks/latest/tasks_v2/types.html#google.cloud.tasks_v2.types.AppEngineHttpRequest.headers

Comment: yeah it seems right. Since the example code they have written http, I thought that for app engine tasks, I need to header within 'http_request' instead of 'app_engine_http_request'. Unfortunately the python sdk docs for google-cloud-taks are pretty useless. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Alex there was indeed a typo with the docs. [This PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/pull/5320/commits/e4834716860252f4477f5c9c5cc972653f05cfc5) should fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Your task have two targets which is App Engine and HTTP. On HTTP, a URL is required as specified in [creating HTTP target tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#creating_http_target_tasks).

The URL must start with 'http://' or 'https://'. To fix the problem, update your `http_request`:

```
'http_request': {                                                   
  'headers': {"Content-type": "application/json"},
  'url': "https://[SERVICE-URL]" + notification_url              
}
```

Or, remove `http_request` and specify your header like this just after declaring your task:

<strike>task["http_request"]["headers"] = {"Content-type": "application/json"}</strike>

**EDIT**:  When specifying App Engine headers, it is also possible to write it down this way:

```
task["app_engine_http_request"]["headers"] = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
```